# How To implement UITableView with multiple buttons in same UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to implement UITableView Where I want to  have 3 buttons in each UITableViewCell, I want to assign Tittles to each buttons Dynamically, if am having all titles in 'title_array
' say then  how can I get the index to an array for giving tittles to each buttons in each UITableViewCell ?

here is my code ,
which is not working,

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   // printf("\ncellForRowAtIndexPath\n");
    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"identifier_%d", indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    //if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //cell.textLabel.text=@"Golbal VC";
    int x=50;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        sample = 0;
    }else{
        if (sample == [titles_array count]-1);
        else sample += 2;
    }


    for(int i =0; i <2 ; i++){


        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x,50,300, 300)];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Canada.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];


        UILabel *tit_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,280,45)];
        [tit_lbl setText:[titles_array objectAtIndex:sample]];
        [btn addSubview:tit_lbl];
        [tit_lbl release];

        UILabel *src_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,65,280,25)];
        [src_lbl setText:[source_array objectAtIndex:sample]];
        [btn addSubview:src_lbl];
        [src_lbl release];

        x=x+350;
        /*if(index == [titles_array count]-1)
            break;
        index++;        
        */
    }

  return cell;


}
```

Comment: Go for custom UITableViewCell. Sample application is provided by Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318)

Comment: build custom cell view or add three buttons programmatically in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @Adhira:that sample code u given does`t help since it uses single button per cell and is easy to implement.

Comment: @Hiren: You can add 3 buttons programmatically but hw will u give the titles dynamically from an array ? if u say indexPath.row for 1st button for the other two buttons what is the index ? i tried with indexPath.row+1,indexPath.row+2 but it duplicates for the 2nd cell ...!? can u give me any sample code ?

Comment: [btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal]

Comment: in your for( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) loop, couldn't you get the title by doing NSString* title = [title_array objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row * 3) + i)]... oh and if you want 3 buttons the for loop should be for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )

Comment: @Ranganath Hello, u got solution for this question ? I m also searching solution from last 2 days. But didn't find. Please help if u get correct solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `titleArray` with `NSDictionary` objects, where you can provide title to your buttons according to the position in the cell( jus for example, you can use anything to identify your buttons).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];         
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    UILabel *tit_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,280,45)];
    [tit_lbl setText:[dict valueForKey:@"titleLabel"]];
    [btn addSubview:tit_lbl];
    [tit_lbl release];  

    UILabel *src_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,65,280,25)];
    [src_lbl setText:[dict valueForKey:@"sourceLabel"]];
    [btn addSubview:src_lbl];
    [src_lbl release];   

    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

You should have to try using this link and create custom cell accordingly and put three buttons in your UITableViewCell XIB file... This is the simplest method for doing this... and assign tag to each button in XIB...

1. http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284
2. http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder
3. http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/